# Gradle Sync not working after using Chaquopy Plugin

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, chaquopy

I am trying to use **Chaquopy Plugin** in my android project generated with flutter. I mean that when a flutter project is created it generates an android project app folder with it. As  Chaquopy does not provide direct support for flutter so I have decided to use this in that flutter generated android app. I went through the line-by-line of Chaquopy's documentation and tried to follow all the instructions given there. But I think I missed something and it is showing errors now and not downloading the Chaquopy Plugin. I am giving my settings.gradle and other gradle files below. Please help me. I am very new to programming and that's why I don't understand these stuff much
[Here is the Chaquopy Documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html)

### Here is my Settings.gradle

```
include ':app'

def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

### Here is my Project level Build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.chaquo.python' version '12.0.1' apply false
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### Here is my App level Build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

plugins {
    id 'com.chaquo.python'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.pyflut"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        python {
            buildPython "C:/Users/super/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe"
            buildPython "C:/Users/super/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe", "-3.10"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

### Finally here are my errors

```
Build file 'F:\Pyflut\android\build.gradle' line: 14

Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.chaquo.python', version: '12.0.1', apply: false]
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration1'.
   > Could not determine artifacts for com.chaquo.python:com.chaquo.python.gradle.plugin:12.0.1
      > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/chaquo/python/com.chaquo.python.gradle.plugin/12.0.1/com.chaquo.python.gradle.plugin-12.0.1.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/chaquo/python/com.chaquo.python.gradle.plugin/12.0.1/com.chaquo.python.gradle.plugin-12.0.1.jar'.
            > Read timed out

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.chaquo.python', version: '12.0.1', apply: false]
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolveToFoundResult(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:215)...... [Can not copy full error because of character limitaions sorry for that but if it needs then I will provide you that
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, it looks like the Gradle plugin portal is having some problems today.

Since your Flutter-generated project uses the old `buildscript` and `apply` syntax to apply the Android plugin, you should probably follow the same pattern with the Chaquopy plugin. That way, the Gradle plugin portal won't even be involved. See [this version](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/10.0/android.html#android-plugin) of the Chaquopy documentation for an example.

Alternatively, you can continue to apply the Chaquopy plugin with the new `plugins` syntax, but also include `mavenCentral` in the `pluginManagement { repositories }` block in settings.gradle. That should allow you to access the plugin without relying on the Gradle plugin portal's mirror. See [here](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy-matplotlib/blob/master/settings.gradle) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Jcenter is down mate. We don't know how long it will be because there is no blogpost or social media post about it.

Check it here: https://status.bintray.com/

[image]